# Vmware workstation 15 very wide messege-box problem

Tags: windows-10, scale, messagebox, vmware-workstation

On vmware workstation 15 with the latest windows 10 1809 update the 
message boxes are very wide.
This is how it looks after clicking on reverting to snapshop:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qPQ2.png)

I have 2 fullhd monitors and this goes on to the entire both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this too. As a workaround I found out that if you do not maximise the VMware Workstation window, message boxes are normal size.